# EL empty condition not working as expected

Tags: dictionary, vector, foreach, jstl

I have a jsp which receives (after validation) a `Map<String, Vector<ErrorMessage>>` called errorList. This contains per attribute on the page a list of errors. The same jsp is also used for the initial entry of the data and in that case no map will be available.

**There fore I created following expression:**

```
<c:if test="${not empty errorList}">
    <div class="warningbox">
        <div class="warning">
            <c:forEach var="error" items="${errorList['PropertyAttribute.KIND']}"/>
                test: ${error.errorMessage}
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

**Things I would expect:**
1. When filling in the form for the first time the errorList does not exist (even verified by checking request.getAttributeNames(). Thus the if body should not be executed. Not true, in reality the if body is executed. ... **Why**?
2. When the Vector is empty the forEach body should never be executed. In reality the result on the page is "test: ". This is just rediculous.

Maybe not an unimportant fact. I use the **google app engine**.

Comment: @JB Nizet. It is not 100% accurate code above. I don't have my code available currently, it is just to explain my problem. ${errorList['attributeName']}

Comment: Changed the code in to the real code.

Answer (score 1):

I see three possibilities:

1. The `errorList` (which really should be named errorMap) is present in the request attributes, and not empty (but you ruled that out)
2. There is a page, or session, or application-scope attribute named `errorList` which is not empty. You could rule that out by using `${not empty requestScope.errorList}`.
3. You see "test" on the page because EL is ignored or because the core tag library is not declared in your JSP. Check the generated HTML code to see how it looks.

Comment: Solved! I had a typo in the include of the core library, thanks!

Comment: Also apparently you cannot link directly to the enum PropertyAttribute in my example as EL has no access to java classes directly. To overcome this I had to set a new var in EL with <%= PropertyKind.KIND.toString() %>. Using that new var then as key on the map works. However to me this is something that is missing in EL. It makes my pages more dynamic, only one spot to change a form item name.